# ReactJS: await function for fetching data returns a pending promise

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, promise

I'm trying to fect data from a firebase database.

However, I have subcollections so I need to first get the id of the document and then get the docs inside the subcollection :

collection --> doucments --> subcollection --> documents

I use this :

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fecthData = async () => {
      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"))
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc);
          var querySnap = await getDocs(collection(db, `users/${doc.id}/general`))
          console.log(querySnap)
        });
      }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    };
    fecthData();
  }, []);
```

This returns the following error :

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: F:\panel_admin\src\pages\Management.js: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (26:26)
```

Removing "await" does return the needed data put in a pending promise ?
How can I get the data normaly like the first document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for...of`. The problem is `forEach((doc)` function is not `async`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"))
        let allDocs = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          allDocs.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
        })
        for (const item of allDocs) {
          const querySnap = await getDocs(collection(db, `users/${item.id}/general`))
          console.log(querySnap)
        }

    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```